# How to use "^" as power in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know that we can use `Math.pow()` as a power function. However I'm making a calculator, and the user might type "^" to do the power function.
Is there any way to use "^" as a power function?
Or some things like ^() will also work.

Comment: use `**` instead.

Comment: Don't use `eval` to implement a calculator. Parse the string, then interpret the operators as you see fit.

Comment: You might find [Parse arithmetic expression with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325832/parse-arithmetic-expression-with-javascript) useful.

Comment: You could do something like this - `let eqn = "5^6"; Math.pow(eqn.split("^")[0], eqn.split("^")[1])`. There are better ways to parse the string.

Comment: Okay, I'll look around how to parse the string

Comment: btw should I use an array to parse or something else?

Comment: @Broccoliy You might tokenize into an array, but in the end you will need a parse *tree*

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, `^` means binary-exclusive-or in Javascript, and Javascript does not allow you to re-map operators.

(And you shouldn’t anyway.  It would quickly become very confusing.)